# Show message if text filter return no result in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lets say we have this ng-repeat with a text filter :

```
<input ng-model="searchFilter" type="text">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchFilter" >
    <label>{{item.label}}</label>

  </li>
</ul>

<p>Sorry, no result</p>
```

I am wondering if it is possible to show a message (`<p>Sorry, no result</p>`) when a text filter return 0 items in a `ng-repeat` ?

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dagevanapi/5/edit) here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure, you can use the following `ng-repeat` syntax:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (items | filter:searchFilter)" >
    <label>{{item.label}}</label>
</li>
<li ng-if="filteredItems.length === 0">No Items Found</li>
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/zepobugexi/2/edit