# Show Message if results are 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a Filter for a Table and want to show no Results if the filter found nothing.
In short the necessary Code:

```
<th>Keys
<input ng-model="k" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Suche...">
            </th>  
<tr dir-paginate="v in result = ($ctrl.langV  | filter:{Name:k}) | orderBy : 'Name' |itemsPerPage: 10">
            <td class="td-keys">{{v.Name}}
            </td>
            <td ng-if="result.length === 0">Keine Ergebnisse</td>
```

I have found allready here a few Examples:

- [Show message if text filter return no result in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502975/show-message-if-text-filter-return-no-result-in-ng-repeat)
- [How to show a message when filter returns nothing in ng-repeat - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524572/how-to-show-a-message-when-filter-returns-nothing-in-ng-repeat-angularjs)
- [AngularJS - placeholder for empty result from filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615495/angularjs-placeholder-for-empty-result-from-filter)
  But none of them working?
  A simple

> ```
>  <td ng-show="result.length">Keine Ergebnisse</td>
> ```

Is showing me the extra td because results are found. But the opposite for no Results never works.
Thx for Solutions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the three examples you referenced, they are displaying the no result message *outside* of the ng-repeat. You are display the no result message *inside* the ng-repeat. Try taking that statement out of the scope of the ng-repeat and see if it works then.

Comment: Outside of the Table it is working. But following the https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat example at the Bottom. it shouldnt be a Problem or ? The ng if is there as well inside the List repeat? 
So what your Solution would be here ?

Comment: That example also has the no result message _outside_ of the scope of the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Ah yeah ok got it. Changed to
`<tr dir-paginate="v in $ctrl.langV  | filter:{Name:k}| orderBy : 'Name' |itemsPerPage: 10 as results ">
            <td class="td-keys">{{v.Name}}
            </td></tr>
  <tr>
            <td ng-if="results.length === 0">Keine Ergebnisse</td>
          </tr>`
Works now and Answer Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use like this... when `no results`, this would show.

```
<td ng-if="!result.length">Keine Ergebnisse</td>
```

Comment: @AkAk47: Then your results should have some objects... what does it give you when you try this in your view {{result}} when there is no results..

Comment: If i go for true `<td ng-if="result.length">{{result}} Keine Ergebnisse</td>` it shows all objects. With !result.length no output again.

Comment: in your controller make your $scope.result = []; an empty array and then try <td ng-if="!result.length">{{result}} Keine Ergebnisse</td>

Comment: Did same result. I dont need a Function or create a .filter for that, do i ?
Because all Examples worked with plain Html + ng-show/if/hide.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to give an *alias* to your *"results"*, something like `filteredItems`, as below:

```
<tr dir-paginate="v in $ctrl.langV | filter: { Name: k } | orderBy : 'Name' | itemsPerPage: 10 as filteredItems">
```

Then, you can use it:

```
<td ng-if="!filteredItems.length">No results</td>
```